# Adding count of list elements into dictionary

Tags: python, typeerror

I am trying to add elements and their count in a list to a dictionary, but getting Type Error. Here is my code :

```py
v= ["a","b","c","b","a"]

res= {}
for i in set(v):
    res.update( i = v.count[i] )
print(res)
```

The error I am getting is:

> TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Your code should be a minimum reproducible example. I can't run the code you've provided and recreate your error. What is votes.count[i]? It's not defined.

Comment: You mean `v.count(i)`, but this is *not* an efficient implementations, it is O(N**2) when you can do it in O(N)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to reinvent the wheel - you can use Python's [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```py
from collections import Counter
v = ["a","b","c","b","a"]
result = Counter(v)
```

And if you absolutely need a dictionary and not just an object that can act like one:

```py
result = dict(Counter(v))
```

Comment: `Counter` isn't merely "an object that can act like one", it *is* a `dict`, i.e. `isinstance(Counter(), dict)` is true